Prove that any subspace $S$ of the vector space $ \mathbb R^n$ is a closed set
Prove that any subspace (sub vector space) $S$ of the vector space $ \mathbb R^n$ is a closed set or, equivalently, that its set
complement $S^c=\mathbb R^n \backslash S$ is open, that is, for any $x \in S^c $ there is an open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$centered at $x$ with radius $ \epsilon>0$ for which $B(x,\epsilon) \subset S^c$
I tried to prove that theorem above by proving that its complement set is open. But I can't. That's what I did:
Let $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a subspace. If $dim(V)=n $ then $V= \mathbb R^n .$ then $V$ is closed.
Let $dim(V)=m<n$
Then when $B=\{b_1,...,b_m\}$ is a basis for $S$ We can find a basis for $\mathbb R^n$ like this $\{b_1,...,b_m,b_{m+1},...,b_n\} $
I can defind a norm such that when $x \in \mathbb R^n $ and
$x=\alpha_1b_1+...+\alpha_m b_m$
$$ \|x\| =( \sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i |^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
So since the all norms in finit dimensional space is equivalent then if I prove that $S$ is closed for this norm then it is closed for euclidean  norm too.
Let $x \in S^c $ then $x= \alpha_1b_1+...+\alpha_m b_m $ and $\exists j $ such that $m<j\le n$ and $\alpha_j \neq 0$
I have to pick an $\epsilon >0$ such that for any $y \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $y=x=\beta_1b_1+...+\beta_m b_m$ and
$$( \sum_{i=1}^n |\alpha_i - \beta_i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \epsilon  $$
then $y \in S^c $
But I can't know how I can choose this epsilon.
Any help?
By the way, I see different ways to solve this problem. There were some proofs with using linear transformation and orthogonal complement. But I can't use them because we haven't study them yet.
Also I found this proof:

Let $(V,\|\cdot \|_V)$ a proper subspace. Suppose that $$V=Span\{v_1,...,v_m\},$$
where $m<n$. Complete it in a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $$Span\{v_1,...,v_{m},v_{m+1},...,v_n\}=\mathbb R^n.$$
Notice that if $v\in V$, then for all $\varepsilon >0$ $$\mathcal B(v,\varepsilon )\cap V^c\neq \emptyset$$
since for example $v+\frac{\varepsilon }{2}v_n\in \mathcal B(v,\varepsilon )\setminus V$ for all $\varepsilon >0$.
I recall that $$\mathcal B(v,\varepsilon )=\{w\in\mathbb N\mid \|v-w\|_V<\varepsilon \}.$$

But I see that in this proof we see that $V \subset \delta V $. But for proving that $V$ is closed we have to prove that $\delta V \subset V $. So it is different. For Example In $\mathbb R $ we Know that $ \mathbb Q \subset \delta \mathbb Q $ But $\mathbb Q$ isn't closed.

Define subspace - I'm guessing you don't mean topological subspace.

@StevenClontz I mean $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $S$ is a vector space.

There are different ways to prove a subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed. For example, $S$ is closed if any sequence in $S$ that converges in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has its limit in $S$. There is also: if a map is continuous, then the inverse image of a closed set is closed.

@Deane I tried the first way but I can't see anything. If ${x_k} \subset S$ s.t. $\lim_k x_k=x $ then $\lim_k ({\alpha_1}^k b_1+...+{\alpha_m}^k b_m)=\beta_1 b_1+....+\beta_m b_m +...+\beta_n b_n$ So I have to prove that $\beta_{m+1}=... =\beta_n=0$ But I didn't know how .

Try the case $n=2$ and $m=1$.

You can prove first that the functions $$\beta_j : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ are continuous (as they are linear and the spaces are finite-dimensional). Then you get everything for free.

Since any vector subspace $S$ of $\mathbf{R}^n$ is either a line through the origin, or a plane through the origin, or a linear subspace of dimension $\leq n$ through the origin, consider a point $x \in S^c$ (when ${\rm dim}(S) < n$) and draw the normal line to the subspace $S$ passing through the point $x$. Since the distance $d > 0$ from the point $x$ to $S$ (as measured on this line) is finite, and this is the shortest distance from the point $x$ to any point on $S$, hence any open ball of radius $d/2$ centred at the point $x$ is fully contained in $S^c$, and hence $S^c$ is open; thereby $S$ is closed. When ${\rm dim}(S) = n$, it follows that $S = \mathbf{R}^n$ and is hence closed.

Why is $d>0$ I know that $d=e(x,S)=inf {e(x,s) : s \in S}$ and if $x \in S^c$ but $x$ is a limit point of $S$ then $d=0$

@A12345 Take the definition of $d$ as the distance (as measured on the normal) from $x$ to the point where the normal intersects $S$. Since $x \in S^c$ and $\mathbf{R}^n$ is a metric space; hence $d > 0$.
